# How to get asynchronously elements number of data using addSnapshotListener

Tags: swiftui

I'm currently developing an application using `SwiftUI` and `Firebase`.

I want to write a code that works like the below, but it doesn't work...

- When creating an instance of `struct`, `onAppear` works and calls
  `addSnapshotListener` in `ViewModel` class, then shows the array's
  element number.

If the `Collection` in `Firestore` has 2 `documents` `Text` part should show `2` but in the case of my code, it always shows `0`.

How could I solve this problem?

---

Here are the codes:

CheckArrayCount.swift

```
import SwiftUI
    
struct CheckArrayCount: View {
    
        @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
        @State var count = 0
    
        var body: some View {
            VStack{
                Text("arrayCount:\(String(count))") // I want to show 2 here because viewModel.array has 2 data
            }
            .onAppear(){
                self.count = self.viewModel.array.count
            }
        }
}
```

ViewModel.swift

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
    
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
        @Published var array = [Any]()
    
        func getCount(){
    
            Firestore.firestore().collection("Posts").addSnapshotListener{ //then Posts has 2 documents
                (snap, err) in
    
                guard let docs = snap else{return}
    
                docs.documentChanges.forEach{ (doc) in
                    self.array.append(doc)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

---

Xcode: Version 12.3

iOS: 14.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're not actually calling `getCount` anywhere. You also don't need the intermediate `@State` variable, since you can access the `@Published` array directly.

This would be a possible solution:

```
struct CheckArrayCount: View {

    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("arrayCount:\(viewModel.array.count)")
        }
        .onAppear(){
            viewModel.getCount()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your code, Your view never updates because you don't use an array (which is Observable) in the whole view. so you also need to define count var inside the view model. Like this

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var array = [Any]()
    @Published var count = 0

    func getCount(){

        Firestore.firestore().collection("Posts").addSnapshotListener{ //then Posts has 2 documents
            (snap, err) in

            guard let docs = snap else{return}

            docs.documentChanges.forEach{ (doc) in
                self.array.append(doc)
            }
           self.count = self.array.count
        }
    }
}
```

and in view part

```
struct CheckArrayCount: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("arrayCount:\(viewModel.count)")
        }
    }
}
```